# SQL - partition by one column and some field types

Tags: sql, hive, window, partition

My table is much bigger but a small snipped would be like:

```
---------+---+----------+--------+------------+---
|distance|qtt|deliver_by| store  |deliver_time| ...
+--------+---+----------+--------+------------|---
|   11   |  1|  pa      | store_a|  1111      |
|   123  |  2|  pa      | store_a|  1112      |
|   33   |  3|  pb      | store_a|  1113      |
|   33   |  2|  pa      | store_b|  2221      |
|   44   |  2|  pb      | store_b|  2222      |
|   5    |  2|  pc      | store_b|  2223      |
|   5    |  2|  pc      | store_b|  2224      |
|   6    |  5|  pb      | store_c|  3331      |
|   7    |  5|  pb      | store_c|  3332      |
----------------------------------------------....
```

there are **multiple stores** but **only 3 possible delivers** (deliver_by: **pa**, **pb** and **pc**) that deliver products at a certain time. Consider `deliver_time` a timestamp.

I want to select the whole table and **add 6 new columns**, **min** and **max** time per `deliver_by` at a store.
A store can be served by any of the 3 delivers (pa, pb, pc) but not necessary.

I could accomplish almost the correct result, with the query below, the **problem** is that in **case** `deliver_by` *pX* is **not present**, I **don't get a null** but instead the min/max for the delivery at the store.

I really would like to use a partition by, so I wrote this to add the new min/max columns:

```
select
  min(deliver_time) over (partition by store, deliver_by='pa') as as min_time_sd_pa
, max(deliver_time) over (partition by store, deliver_by='pa') as as min_time_sd_pa

, min(deliver_time) over (partition by store, deliver_by='pb') as as min_time_sd_pb
, max(deliver_time) over (partition by store, deliver_by='pb') as as min_time_sd_pb

, min(deliver_time) over (partition by store, deliver_by='pc') as as min_time_sd_pc
, max(deliver_time) over (partition by store, deliver_by='pc') as as min_time_sd_pc

, distance, qtt, ....
from mytable
```

the **correct output would be**:

```
min_time_sd_pa|max_time_sd_pa|min_time_sd_pb|max_time_sd_pb|min_time_sd_pc|max_time_sd_pc|distance|qtt|deliver_by| store  |deliver_time
--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+---+----------+--------+------------
    1111      |  1112        |  1113        |   1113       |   null       |   null       |   11   |  1| pa       | store_a| 1111
    1111      |  1112        |  1113        |   1113       |   null       |   null       |   123  |  2| pa       | store_a| 1112
    1111      |  1112        |  1113        |   1113       |   null       |   null       |   33   |  3| pb       | store_a| 1113
    2221      |  2221        |  2222        |   2222       |   2223       |   2224       |   33   |  2| pa       | store_b| 2221
    2221      |  2221        |  2222        |   2222       |   2223       |   2224       |   44   |  2| pb       | store_b| 2222
    2221      |  2221        |  2222        |   2222       |   2223       |   2224       |   5    |  2| pc       | store_b| 2223
    2221      |  2221        |  2222        |   2222       |   2223       |   2224       |   5    |  2| pc       | store_b| 2224
    null      |  null        |  null        |   null       |   3331       |   3332       |   6    |  5| pb       | store_c| 3331
    null      |  null        |  null        |   null       |   3331       |   3332       |   7    |  5| pb       | store_c| 3332
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is missing in my `select min(..) over..` statement or how could I accomplish this result in the most simple way?
I am using *Hive QL*, but I guess this is generic across most *SQL DBMS*.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a `case` expression in `min` and `max`.

```
select
 min(case when deliver_by='pa' then deliver_time end) over (partition by store) as min_time_sd_pa
,max(case when deliver_by='pa' then deliver_time end) over (partition by store) as max_time_sd_pa
,min(case when deliver_by='pb' then deliver_time end) over (partition by store) as min_time_sd_pb
,max(case when deliver_by='pb' then deliver_time end) over (partition by store) as max_time_sd_pb
,min(case when deliver_by='pc' then deliver_time end) over (partition by store) as min_time_sd_pc
,max(case when deliver_by='pc' then deliver_time end) over (partition by store) as max_time_sd_pc
,m.*
from mytable m
```